# ¿Cómo limitar los datos mostrados en un datalist input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un `input` donde filtro los datos de un datalist, mientras se filtra me gustaría solo mostrar un máximo 10 o 5 `items`, ya que me despliega una lista muy larga de datos en pantalla.
Este es mi ejemplo y  exede el numero de datos que quiero mostrar:

```html
<input type="text" id="myprod" onblur="" list="listprod" class="form-control " placeholder="Buscar Producto">
<datalist id="listprod">
    <option id="10212124545" data-codigo="00" value="FLETE">10212124545</option>
    <option id="1245245" data-codigo="AJU0001" value="AJUSTE">1245245</option>
    <option id="123213213" data-codigo="BOL01" value="MANGA TRANSP. 20 CM">123213213
    </option>
    <option id="12312312" data-codigo="BOL02" value="MANGA TRANSP. 30 CM">12312312</option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="BOL03" value="MANGA TRANSP. 30CM"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="BOL04" value="MANGA TRANSP. 40 CM"></option>
    <option id="4564645645" data-codigo="CHC0001" value="AGENDA DE SALUD CONTROL PRENATAL">4564645645</option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0002" value="MI LIBRO DE RELACIONES ESP MAPUDUNG"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0003" value="MI LIBRO DE RELACIONES ESPECIALES"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0004" value="MI LIBRO DE NUMEROS "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0007" value="IMAGENES MOVIL "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0008" value="MI LIBRO DE VOCALES "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0009" value="MI LIBRO FIG. GEOMETRICAS "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0010" value="ACOMPAÑANDOTE A DESCUBRIR I"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0011" value="ACOMPAÑANDOTE A DESCUBRIR II"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0012" value="PATERNIDAD ACTIVA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0013" value="CANCIONES PARA CERECER CONTIGO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0014" value="JUGUEMOS EN EL CAMPO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0015" value="CONTEMOS UNA HISTORIA "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0016" value="CUENTOS PARA CANTAR CONTIGO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0018" value="LIBRO APOYO SICOSOCIAL EN SIT. EMER"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC019" value="NADIE ES PERFECTO DESARROLLO FISICO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC020" value="NADIE ES PERFECTO PADRES, MADRES Y "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC021" value="NADIE ES PERFECTO SEG. Y PREVENCION"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC022" value="NADIE ES PERFECTO DESARROLLO MENTAL"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC023" value="NADIE ES PERFECTO COMPORTAMIENTO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC024" value="CUADERNILLO REGISTROVISITA DOM."></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC025" value="PAUTA DERIVACION A SALA ESTIMULACIO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC026" value="PROGRAMA DE APOYO RN"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC027" value="REGISTRO CONTACTO NIÑO (A)"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC028" value="VIDEO EJERCICIOS PRENATALES "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC029" value="MATERIAL AUDIOV. PARA CRIANZA RESP."></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC030" value="REGISTRO CONTACTO GESTANTE "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC031" value="CUNAS RN"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC032" value="PACK PISO GOMA EVA "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC033" value="PACK APEGO SEGURO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC034" value="PACK CUIDADOS BASICOS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC035" value="CARTILLA APOYO EN CRIANZA "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC036" value="FOLLETO PAPA MAMA LACTANCIA MATERNA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC037" value="FOLLETO INVITACION CONTROL PRENATAL"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC038" value="FOLLETO HORA DE SER PADRE "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHCR005" value="GALLETAS VARIEDAD"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHCR006" value="CEREAL BARRA "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHCR017" value="EMPEZANDO A CRECER GUIA GESTACION "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSO0002" value="COLONIA FEMENINA ANGELICA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSO0003" value="JABON LIQUIDO 1 LITRO CS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSO0004" value="SHAMPOO 1 LITRO CS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSO0005" value="EMULSIONADO  CS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSO0006" value="COLONIA MASCULINA CS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSOC001" value="DESODORANTE CORPORAL CS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV" value="UNIDAD REFRIGERANTE "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV01" value="VOLANTES ACV"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV02" value="VOLANTES IAM"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV03" value="DIPTRICOS ADHERENCIA AL TTO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV04" value="CALENDARIOS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV05" value="CARPETAS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV06" value="FOLLETO 8 FRCV"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV07" value="BOLSOS TERMICOS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV08" value="IMANES CALENDARIO MEDICAMENTOS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV09" value="TRIPTICOS PIE DM"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV10" value="BOLSAS ECOLOGICAS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV11" value="INDIVIDUALES AFICHES "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV12" value="MONOFILAMENTOS PIE DIABETICO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV13" value="BOTA PIE DIABETICO L"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV14" value="BOTA PIE DIABETICO M"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV15" value="BOTA PIE DIABETICO S"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV16" value="RECETARIO PRODUCTOS DEL MAR "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV17" value="RECETARIO SALUDABLE "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV18" value="RECETARIO SALUDABLE ANILLADO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV19" value="FOLLETO CARTILLA DEL PACIENTE"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV20" value="FOLLETO TOMA MUESTRA BACILOSCOPIA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV21" value="BLOCK IAM"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV22" value="BLOCK ACV"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV23" value="FOLLETO DIABETES Y CUIDADO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV24" value="CARPETA CARDIOV."></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV25" value="CUADERNILLO TIENE ALGUNA DUDA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV26" value="CUADERNO CONTROL DIABETICO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV27" value="FOLLETO PREV. Y CUIDADO PIES "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV28" value="HIDROGEL CV 15 GRS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV29" value="APOSITO C/PLATA Y FIBRA REFUERZO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV30" value="APOSITO DE ESPUMA C/PLATA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV31" value="SOLUCION LAVADO DE HERIDAS "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV32" value="APOSITO C/SOL. RINGER "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV33" value="VENDA FIJACION 8CMX4M"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV34" value="APOSITO ADHESION BACT. 10X10"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: para lo que necesitas existen plugins que lo hacen de una manera fabulosa Si usas select, recomiendo usar [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) Si usas datalist, recomiendo usar [FlexDataList](http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/) Saludos!

Comment: Estimado gracias por su  ayuda  y consejos soy nuevo en esto :) Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente no se le puede cambiar los estilos a los elementos `datalist` y tampoco disponen de un atributo para poder controlar el tamaño máximo.

Las soluciones son hacer una pequeña función de JS para arreglar tu problema, o elegir una libreria que directamente nos ofrece esta funcionalidad:

**Alternativas:**

- [Bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)
- [jQuery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

**Función JS usando `datalist`**

```js
var search = document.querySelector('#myprod');
var results = document.querySelector('#listprod');
var templateContent = document.querySelector('#listtemplate').content;
search.addEventListener('keyup', function handler(event) {
    while (results.children.length) results.removeChild(results.firstChild);
    var inputVal = new RegExp(search.value.trim(), 'i');
    var set = Array.prototype.reduce.call(templateContent.cloneNode(true).children, function searchFilter(frag, item, i) {
        if (inputVal.test(item.value) && frag.children.length < 6) frag.appendChild(item);
        return frag;
    }, document.createDocumentFragment());
    results.appendChild(set);
});
```

```html
<template id="listtemplate"> 
    <option id="10212124545" data-codigo="00" value="FLETE">10212124545</option>
    <option id="1245245" data-codigo="AJU0001" value="AJUSTE">1245245</option>
    <option id="123213213" data-codigo="BOL01" value="MANGA TRANSP. 20 CM">123213213</option>
    <option id="12312312" data-codigo="BOL02" value="MANGA TRANSP. 30 CM">12312312</option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="BOL03" value="MANGA TRANSP. 30CM"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="BOL04" value="MANGA TRANSP. 40 CM"></option>
    <option id="4564645645" data-codigo="CHC0001" value="AGENDA DE SALUD CONTROL PRENATAL">4564645645</option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0002" value="MI LIBRO DE RELACIONES ESP MAPUDUNG"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0003" value="MI LIBRO DE RELACIONES ESPECIALES"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0004" value="MI LIBRO DE NUMEROS "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0007" value="IMAGENES MOVIL "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0008" value="MI LIBRO DE VOCALES "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0009" value="MI LIBRO FIG. GEOMETRICAS "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0010" value="ACOMPAÑANDOTE A DESCUBRIR I"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0011" value="ACOMPAÑANDOTE A DESCUBRIR II"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0012" value="PATERNIDAD ACTIVA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0013" value="CANCIONES PARA CERECER CONTIGO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0014" value="JUGUEMOS EN EL CAMPO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0015" value="CONTEMOS UNA HISTORIA "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0016" value="CUENTOS PARA CANTAR CONTIGO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC0018" value="LIBRO APOYO SICOSOCIAL EN SIT. EMER"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC019" value="NADIE ES PERFECTO DESARROLLO FISICO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC020" value="NADIE ES PERFECTO PADRES, MADRES Y "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC021" value="NADIE ES PERFECTO SEG. Y PREVENCION"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC022" value="NADIE ES PERFECTO DESARROLLO MENTAL"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC023" value="NADIE ES PERFECTO COMPORTAMIENTO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC024" value="CUADERNILLO REGISTROVISITA DOM."></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC025" value="PAUTA DERIVACION A SALA ESTIMULACIO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC026" value="PROGRAMA DE APOYO RN"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC027" value="REGISTRO CONTACTO NIÑO (A)"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC028" value="VIDEO EJERCICIOS PRENATALES "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC029" value="MATERIAL AUDIOV. PARA CRIANZA RESP."></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC030" value="REGISTRO CONTACTO GESTANTE "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC031" value="CUNAS RN"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC032" value="PACK PISO GOMA EVA "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC033" value="PACK APEGO SEGURO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC034" value="PACK CUIDADOS BASICOS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC035" value="CARTILLA APOYO EN CRIANZA "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC036" value="FOLLETO PAPA MAMA LACTANCIA MATERNA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC037" value="FOLLETO INVITACION CONTROL PRENATAL"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHC038" value="FOLLETO HORA DE SER PADRE "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHCR005" value="GALLETAS VARIEDAD"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHCR006" value="CEREAL BARRA "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CHCR017" value="EMPEZANDO A CRECER GUIA GESTACION "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSO0002" value="COLONIA FEMENINA ANGELICA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSO0003" value="JABON LIQUIDO 1 LITRO CS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSO0004" value="SHAMPOO 1 LITRO CS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSO0005" value="EMULSIONADO  CS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSO0006" value="COLONIA MASCULINA CS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CSOC001" value="DESODORANTE CORPORAL CS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV" value="UNIDAD REFRIGERANTE "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV01" value="VOLANTES ACV"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV02" value="VOLANTES IAM"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV03" value="DIPTRICOS ADHERENCIA AL TTO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV04" value="CALENDARIOS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV05" value="CARPETAS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV06" value="FOLLETO 8 FRCV"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV07" value="BOLSOS TERMICOS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV08" value="IMANES CALENDARIO MEDICAMENTOS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV09" value="TRIPTICOS PIE DM"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV10" value="BOLSAS ECOLOGICAS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV11" value="INDIVIDUALES AFICHES "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV12" value="MONOFILAMENTOS PIE DIABETICO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV13" value="BOTA PIE DIABETICO L"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV14" value="BOTA PIE DIABETICO M"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV15" value="BOTA PIE DIABETICO S"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV16" value="RECETARIO PRODUCTOS DEL MAR "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV17" value="RECETARIO SALUDABLE "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV18" value="RECETARIO SALUDABLE ANILLADO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV19" value="FOLLETO CARTILLA DEL PACIENTE"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV20" value="FOLLETO TOMA MUESTRA BACILOSCOPIA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV21" value="BLOCK IAM"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV22" value="BLOCK ACV"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV23" value="FOLLETO DIABETES Y CUIDADO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV24" value="CARPETA CARDIOV."></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV25" value="CUADERNILLO TIENE ALGUNA DUDA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV26" value="CUADERNO CONTROL DIABETICO "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV27" value="FOLLETO PREV. Y CUIDADO PIES "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV28" value="HIDROGEL CV 15 GRS"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV29" value="APOSITO C/PLATA Y FIBRA REFUERZO"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV30" value="APOSITO DE ESPUMA C/PLATA"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV31" value="SOLUCION LAVADO DE HERIDAS "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV32" value="APOSITO C/SOL. RINGER "></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV33" value="VENDA FIJACION 8CMX4M"></option>
    <option id="" data-codigo="CV34" value="APOSITO ADHESION BACT. 10X10"></option>
</template>
<input type="text" id="myprod" onblur="" list="listprod" class="form-control " placeholder="Buscar Producto">
<datalist id="listprod">
</datalist>
```

---

**[Respuesta original en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097563/limit-total-entries-displayed-by-datalist)** de [Olli K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2416376/olli-k)

Comment: Con esta respuesta tardía se busca dar respuesta a una pregunta "valida", para poder ayudar a las estadísticas del sitio por el problema que comenta @Fedorqui en meta [Respuesta de Fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4341/128699)

Answer (score 0):

Una pregunta sobre el ejemplo con Función JS usando datalist.
Como sería si tengo dos  pero ambos pueden seleccionar del mismo datalist?

El ejemplo seria seleccionar origen y seleccionar destino.
GRACIAS !!

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/374347)